# Are there named groups in Groovy regex pattern matches?

Tags: regex, groovy

Something like:

```
def match = "John 19" =~ /(&name&)\w+ (&age&\d+)/
def name = match.name
def age = match.age
```

Is there a groovy syntax that allows for something like this (instead of of the fictional `&` operator I made up?

Comment: Not that I've seen. Good luck.

Comment: Is there any language that allows this kind of matching using regexps?

Comment: Perl, python, ruby...  It's a pretty standard regex feature.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Assuming you are using on Java 7+, you can do:

```
def matcher = 'John 19' =~ /(?<name>\w+) (?<age>\d+)/
if( matcher.matches() ) {
  println "Matches"
  assert matcher.group( 'name' ) == 'John'
  assert matcher.group( 'age' ) == '19'
}
else {
  println "No Match"
}
```

If you are not on java 7 yet, you'd need a [third party regex library](https://code.google.com/p/named-regexp/)

Answer (score 20):

This doesn't name the groups, but a closure does parameterise the match:

```
("John 19" =~ /(\w+) (\d+)/).each {match, name, age ->
  println match
  println name
  println age
}
```

which outputs:

```
John 19
John
19
```

This is a useful reference: http://naleid.com/blog/2008/05/19/dont-fear-the-regexp/

Comment: If you just want the number 19 as output you can do like this: 
`println "John 19".find( /(\w+) (\d+)/) {it[2]}`

Comment: Wow @SebastianVilstrup thanks ... groovy really is a mess! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Alternative:

```
def foo = '''(id:(1 2 3)) OR (blubb)
(id:(4 5 6)) OR (fasel)
'''
​def matcher =  (foo =~ /\(id:\((.+)\)\) OR (.*)/)
def (whole, bar, baz) = matcher[0]
assert whole == '(id:(1 2 3)) OR (blubb)'
assert bar == '1 2 3'
assert baz == '(blubb)'

(whole, bar, baz) = matcher[1]
assert whole == '(id:(4 5 6)) OR (fasel)'
assert bar == '4 5 6'
assert baz == '(fasel)'
```