# Groovy regex named capturing groups must call matches method?

Tags: regex, groovy

I was trying to use regex named capturing group in Groovy.
The example code in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15664318/are-there-named-groups-in-groovy-regex-pattern-matches) works:

```
def matcher = 'John 19' =~ /(?<name>\w+) (?<age>\d+)/
if( matcher.matches() ) {
  println "Matches"
  assert matcher.group( 'name' ) == 'John'
  assert matcher.group( 'age' ) == '19'
}
else {
  println "No Match"
}
```

But if I remove the if statement as follows:

```
def matcher = 'John 19' =~ /(?<name>\w+) (?<age>\d+)/
println "Matches"
assert matcher.group( 'name' ) == 'John'
assert matcher.group( 'age' ) == '19'
```

Groovy complains:

```
Matches
Caught: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No match found
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No match found
    at java_util_regex_Matcher$group.call(Unknown Source)
    at test.run(test.groovy:3)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
```

Why is that? I think `matches()` just return whether the given string matches the regex?

I am using Groovy Version: 2.5.4 JVM: 11.0.1 Vendor: Oracle Corporation OS: Mac OS X

Thanks!

Comment: You're not using the same regex between examples.

Comment: Sorry, I have edited the question using example code in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15664318/are-there-named-groups-in-groovy-regex-pattern-matches