# Why can you not call a regex matcher's methods inline in Groovy

Tags: regex, groovy

I'm currently learning groovy, more for fun than necessity, but I've hit something which I don't really understand.

If I run the following:

```
["SEMOLINA_0001"].collect {
    def m = it =~ /SEMOLINA_([A-Fa-f0-9]+)/
    println m
    assert m
    println m
    return m.group(1)
}
```

I get the result:

```
java.util.regex.Matcher[pattern=SEMOLINA_([A-Fa-f0-9]+) region=0,13 lastmatch=]
java.util.regex.Matcher[pattern=SEMOLINA_([A-Fa-f0-9]+) region=0,13 lastmatch=SEMOLINA_0001]
Result: [0001]
```

If I remove the `assert`, I get a "No match found" exception on the `.group(1)` call.

I can work around this obviously, but I don't like language behaviour I don't understand - I wouldn't have thought that `assert` would have side-effects, so is this a bug or is this intentional behaviour that I've just not grasped?

(For what it may be worth, I'm using Groovy 2.5.5 in the above example.)

I've also just noticed [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54193783/430967) which was closed as a dupe, though I think mistakenly, since the problem the user was having seemed more like this one rather than anything to do with named groups per se.

Comment: The problem with this and the other question is not the "named" group, but the fact that the matcher was not run before accessing the group. You may only access the matches with the native Groovy code, but to get access to the groups, you must use something like `matches()` or `find()`, or `assert` as in your case.

Comment: Ah, I see - it's been so long since I've used regexes in java proper, I'd forgotten a Matcher needed a matches() call before you could get the groups out of it.
If you want to transpose your comment into a proper answer, I'll mark it as accepted.

Comment: @StuartWood `matches()` or `find()`. That's why it is not auto-executed, because the `Matcher` doesn't know which of the two you intend to use.

Comment: to complete @WiktorStribiżew answer... "assert m" will make a boolean transformation on the matcher m, which basically calls matches().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the `Matcher` was not "run", executed, before accessing the group. You may only access the matches with the native Groovy code, but to get access to the *groups*, you must use some `Matcher` "running" method, like `matches()` or `find()`.

Note that `assert` in your case makes a boolean transformation on the `Matcher`, which eventually calls `matches()` (as [noted by blackdrag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54508257/why-can-you-not-call-a-regex-matchers-methods-inline-in-groovy/54532667#comment95854574_54508257)).

It makes sense that the `Matcher` is not run automatically, because it doesn't know which exact method - `matches()` or `find()` - the user intends to use (as [noted by Andreas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54508257/why-can-you-not-call-a-regex-matchers-methods-inline-in-groovy/54532667#comment95822282_54508257)).